# Verificar se os atributos de um objeto são nulos de uma forma menos manual

Tags: java

Como solucionar isso:

```
Objeto obj = new Objeto();

if(obj != null){
  //executa o codigo
}
```

A pergunta é: eu instanciei o objeto, beleza? Só que eu não defini nenhum valor para ele então, todos os atributos dele estão vazios.

Caso eu faça uma comparação para ver se o objeto é nulo, ele vai me retornar falso. Como faço para verificar se todos os atributos do objeto são nulos ou se o objeto é nulo depois de ser instanciado sem que eu precise sair verificando cada atributo do objeto?

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais apropriada para garantir que os atributos de um objeto estão devidamente definidos é forçando a inicialização deles durante a inicialização do objeto.

É boa prática que todos os atributos de um objeto sejam `final`. Atributos `final` dever ser inicializados até o construtor do objeto terminar.

Exemplo:

```
public class MeuObjeto {
    private final String atributo1;
    private final int atributo2;
    public MeuObjeto(String atributo1, int atributo 2) {
        this.atributo1 = atributo1;
        this.atributo2 = atributo2;
    }
    //getters
}
```

Se, por alguma razão, seu objeto não pode ser imutável, então você não vai poder usar o `final`, mas ainda pode forçar que todos os atributos estejam inicializados usando o construtor.

```
public class MeuObjeto {
    private String atributo1;
    private int atributo2;
    public MeuObjeto(String atributo1, int atributo 2) {
        this.atributo1 = atributo1;
        this.atributo2 = atributo2;
    }
    //getters
    //setters
}
```

Entretanto, tenha em mente que objetos mutáveis são causa comum de problemas em diversos cenários e não só para concorrência como se costuma pensar.

Todo esse "problema" descrito na pergunta, relacionado a ter um objeto com estado indefinido, na verdade só existe devido a um modelo "fraco" de objetos que permite que eles cheguem nesse estado.

Para cada cenário existe uma estratégia diferente para modelar bem um objeto e a regra geral é, evite deixar mutável o que não precisa ser mudado.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem jeito.

Pense bem: como o Java saberia que seu objeto é "nulo"? O nulo que você está propondo é **semântico**, ou seja, depende da sua interpretação dos dados do objeto. Digamos que a classe do objeto em questão tenha um atributo do tipo `int` com o valor `0` num dado momento. Esse `0` significa "ausência de valor" ou a presença de um valor específico, que por acaso é `0`?

Por esse motivo, não tem como o Java fornecer esse tipo de coisa para você- ele não tem como ler sua mente (ou a descrição dos seus requisitos).

O que pode ser feito é usar um método na classe que vai fazer essa verificação. Como é um método, você não vai precisar se preocupar com repetição de código: só vai escrever ele uma vez. Isso aconteceu com a classe String, que ganhou um método `isEmpty`.

Portanto, faça um `isEmpty` na sua classe `Objeto` e use-o assim:

```
Objeto obj = new Objeto();

if(obj && !obj.isEmpty()){
  //executa o codigo
}
```

O funcionamento do `isEmpty()`, é claro, vai depender completamente do seu conceito de `Objeto` vazio.